# How can I stop duplicate QMetaObject definitions across macOS shared libraries?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, casting

The following `qobject_cast()` fails on macOS 10.12.2/clang (and works on RHEL6/gcc) because there are duplicate `QMetaObject` definitions for our `Handler` class:

```
void AbstractDataView::getSelected()
{
   qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << QObject::sender()
        << QObject::sender()->metaObject()
        << &Handler::staticMetaObject;
   Handler *h = qobject_cast<Handler*>(QObject::sender());

   if(h)
      this->getSelected(h);
   else
      qDebug() << "could not find handler to get selected data points"
               << h;
}
```

The above prints:

```
DEBUG: void AbstractDataView::getSelected() Handler(0x7f9674011780, name = "Export Metadata-7f9674011780") 0x1009d4930 0x1113a1310 
DEBUG: could not find handler to get selected data points QObject(0x0)
```

The above code is in a shared library plugin (implemented via the Qt plugin macros `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` et al.) that is loaded by our application; the `Handler` class (derived from `QAction`) instances are constructed by the executable and passed to the shared library plugin constructor.  `Handler` is defined in a static library that is built into both the application and the shared library plugins.

[This](https://forum.qt.io/topic/10806/failing-qobject_cast/25) seems to describe my problem, and suggests that I need to compile the `Handler` definition into its own dynamic library (rather than a static one).  Since that would cause a lot of headaches:

- is this really my problem: would moving `Handler` to a shared library and dynamically loading it within the application and the existing plugins really fix this?
- is there really no simpler way to fix this, particularly since this works fine on linux (RHEL6)?

I can provide CMakeList snippets if that would help, but I thought this was long enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide a barely-satisfactory answer to this myself but would love for someone to provide a better one.  In short:

- moving `Handler` to a shared library does work... kind of.
- the only "simpler" way to fix this that I have found is to use `reinterpret_cast<Handler*>`.  Which "works" in the sense I found no immediate problems, but I sure as heck don't trust it, and as it turns out the shared library solution is only barely more involved (I was thinking about using dynamic loading vs. just linking).

After doing this, I do indeed get a single QMetaObject:

```
DEBUG: void AbstractDataView::getSelected() Handler(0x7fa9eae0b9e0, name = "Export Metadata-7fa9eae0b9e0") 0x10e840350 0x10e840350
```

But the `qobject_cast` still fails!  Fortunately, `dynamic_cast<>` does work (so I have something safer than `reinterpret_cast<>`), but I can't say I quite understand what's going on.